# How to build a matrix $M \in Mat_{1000 \times 1000}(\mathbb{R})$ to represent all possible combinations of a 6 digits code

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, discrete-mathematics, soft-question

Given the digits 0-9 (10 digits), I was asked how many possible combinations of a 6 digits code can be build. Answer is obviously $10^6$. Then I was being asked further questions, and in order to be able to develop an intuition for this kind of questions, I would like to construct a matrix that will represent all possible codes.

More specifically: thr matrix will provide more information regarding special code combinations, such as the number of codes that contain the digit $0$ exactly once, or number of codes containing the digits $0$ and $2$ at least one.

My question is in what way this matrix should be constructed, meaning what are the cordinates that will cover all $10^6$ possible code combinations.

Comment: Do you need them ordered? Otherwise a set might be better than a matrix. Or a tree/graph.

Comment: I'm interested in specific code combinations - for example - all code combinations for which the digit $0$ appear only once, or all combinations for which the digit $0$ appear at least twice, or all the code combinations for which the digits $0$ and $2$ appear exactly once - and so on.

Comment: If you do not need to know where the digits are, perhaps a set of multisets should be chosen?

Comment: how do I construct such one?

Comment: I would do a couple of for loops.

Comment: Actually a multiset of multisets might take more symmetries in consideration, and not loose information. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you require matrices.
This seems to be more combinatorics.
For combinations of codes where 0 appears once, we want 1 zero and 5 non zero. Which is $9^5$ times 6 for the 6 places where 0 could be.
Was this helpful?